# Move command disabled in source control

Tags: version-control

I currently have to clean up some sources in our TFS source control. For some reasons the move command is disabled in the menu for some folders. I was able to move other folders just fine.

Why is it greyed out for some folders?

- I am logged in as TFS administrator
- I got the latest version of the sources
- All folders are mapped
- No pending changes from any user

Any idea?

Comment: What exact version of TFS do you use ?

Comment: Is it a root mapping issue (like in http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/tfsversioncontrol/thread/747fed72-213e-4d30-a630-4f674a05d384/)?

Comment: Thx VonC, that was the problem! Make it an answer, so I can choose it.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

This is usually because you don't have the parent folder mapped locally.

Also, it can occur if the parent folder is mapped to a different location so as the structure of local mapping does not match the structure of server folders.

Comment: So how do I get around it? When you say parent folder, what do you mean? I have my collection and my team project and I have folders inside the team project. I have multiple team projects in the same collection. I have each folder mapped locally. The MOVE and RENAME is disabled for me.

Comment: I solved my issue by using [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14590507/6329629) answer.

Answer (score 4):

Another thing you should verify is that the whole folder you're trying to move is presented locally. Meaning you have to do the `Get Latest Version` prior to moving the folder.

After all sources under the folder are presented locally the `Move...` option becomes available.