# Latest value = "Not Downloaded"

Tags: tfs

I have several projects in TFS which visually appear in the directory hierarchy as grayed out.  When I browse within the projects in Visual Studio 2010/Source Control/TFS 2010, I notice that all of their contents have a Latest value of "Not downloaded".  Normally, I have only seen Latest values of "Yes" or "No".

- I have tried all of the varieties of "Get latest" that I know, but I am always alerted that "All files are up to date".
- If I try to "Check out for edit", I am not allowed.
- When I observe the properties of these grayed out files, they always say Workspace Version = "Not applicable".

How do I fix TFS so that I can download and check out the projects again?  My suspicion is that my workspace is messed up, but I do not know what to do to restore/reconfigure it.

Comment: Did you turn `show deleted files` on?

Comment: I have it turned off.  Should I turn it on for any particular reason?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

I was able to remap the directory to fix my issue.  To do this, I

- selected (right-clicked) the branch that included all of my code, and selected "Remove Mapping..."
- renamed the folder I was mapped to within TFS (you can delete it as well, but I renamed just to keep it during this experimental process)
- created a new folder with the original name of the branch I was mapped to in the beginning, and
- selected (right-clicked) the branch that included all of my code, and selected "Map to Local Folder".

This process forces a complete re-download of the entire branch.  Luckily for me, my branch was only 2GB, so I was able to re-download in about 5-10 minutes.

Comment: I had this exact same problem today. Attempted to clone one branch, then attempted to add some projects that I had stored locally, to the new branch. But when I checked them in, this happened. Was a little worried at first. But found this post and tried it and it fixed the issue. Not sure what happened, but this worked.

Answer (score 7):

The reason for getting "All files are up to date" - is that the information on the TFS server and the files on your disk is out of sync. If you delete the files on your disk with file explorer - the TFS server still thinks you have the file on disk. To re-sync you have to force an update like this:

[image: Get Specific Version...]

Check the two checkbox on this dialog - and click **Get**:

[image: Get dialog]

Comment: I was not this explicit in my original post, but when I was saying I tried all varieties of get latest that I knew, I was referring to the technique you are outlining.  It does not work for me.

Comment: This (sort of) worked for me. In my case Get Specific Version was grayed out. I did Get Latest Version and overwrote the local version and everything is back to normal.

Answer (score 1):

It happened to me as well when I added and existing project as a reference to another project.

When I added the project reference I had a pop-up message that told me that the current project already exists at the source control but at a different location then the relative path of the current project.

by a mistake I choose the wrong option which lead to the unnecessary mapping.

In order to solve this issue I've removed the mapping from the workspace.

only after removing the mapping i could get the latest project.

Comment: Was the second project in a second solution? I think it gets confused when you reference a project in another solution / separate workspace.

Answer (score 1):

I solved it by following this - remove the work space and then tfs prompted me to download everything again. 
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181386(v=vs.100).aspx

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like the folders / files in TFS are not mapped to a local drive in your workspace.

In Source Control Explorer, select the "Workspace:" dropdown, then select "Workspaces".

Choose your current workspace form the list that appears, then hit "Edit". Check that the TFS folder `$/blah` is mapped to a local folder `c:\tfs\blah`

You should now be able to get latest, check out etc.

Comment: Unfortunately, TFS will sometimes show this issue despite the fact that the workspace is mapped and nothing changed.

Answer (score 0):

I had some weirdness with this after :

- updating to TFS2017
- updating to VS2017
- trying to change my TFS URL to https (gave up and reverted back to http)

So somewhere along the line this broke my workspace such that all my projects were showing as unbound. I was able to do a get latest again. This should not overwrite any files you have changed providing they are writable, but if you have any doubt whatsoever then backup your local workspace before doing get latest. It will ask you to resolve conflicts - so make sure to select 'keep local copy'.

Comment: I started experiencing the same thing after going to VS2017.  And it has now happened FOUR times. All of a sudden all of my projects show NOT DOWNLOADED.  I've had to re-download each time.  It's showing NO PENDING CHANGES and I know I have some.  The dates on the files show today's date so there are changes in there.  This is driving my crazy.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, when the branch was deleted: Right click + Check in,  helped.